# SQL bulk + stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

Error: The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination. Does some one have a idea on how to resolve this issue? Is it giving the error because i'm trying to get my TreinId by treinNaam, which is stored in a different table? or? i'm using SQL server management studio 2008

Any help is much appreciated!

```
public void BatchBulkCopy(string rapport)
        {
            // Get the DataTable 
            DataTable dtInsertRows = TextReader(rapport);

            using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {
                sbc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Fouten";
                sbc.BatchSize = 2000;


                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Datum", "Datum");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Foutcode", "FoutCode");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Omschrijving", "Omschrijving");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Module", "Module");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Time", "Time");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Teller", "Teller");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Mnemo", "Mnemo");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("treinNaam", "treinNaam");

                sbc.NotifyAfter = dtInsertRows.Rows.Count;
                sbc.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(sbc_SqlRowsCopied);

                sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
                sbc.Close();
            }

        }

        void sbc_SqlRowsCopied(object sender, SqlRowsCopiedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Datatable filed by:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { datum, foutcode, omschrijving, test[test.Length - 1],tijd,teller,absentOfPresent,TreinNaam });
return dt;
```

SQL stored procedure:

```
USE [Events]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_BatchInsert]    Script Date: 03/15/2016 09:13:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BatchInsert] (@Datum date, @Foutcode varchar(8), @Omschrijving varchar(50), @Module varchar(20), @Time time(3), @Teller int, @Mnemo varchar(9), @treinNaam int)
AS
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.Fouten VALUES (@Datum,@Foutcode,@Omschrijving,@Module,@Time,@Teller,@Mnemo,(SELECT TreinId from [Events].[dbo].[Treinen] WHERE Name = @treinNaam));
END
```

Database design:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That stored procedure code doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: `sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("treinNaam", "treinId");`

Comment: Seems to be it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From DBMS perspective TreinNaam doesn't exist in this context. It has to be column available in Fouten.

You have 2 choices here:

1. Find all treinId in advance and replace treinNaam with treinId
2. Create staging table and dump data as you have, then write stored proc which will take care of moving data into Fouten and find all required connections